# Roll back of Ubuntu installation possible to get a WIN7 partition back?

Tags: installation, partitioning, uninstall

After testing Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) by booting it from the CD, I unfortunately decided to install it on my pc. On my pc I had kept on each hd and the ssd as well space enough for other partitions. I used the offered option to install Ubuntu alongside with Win7 and ... ended up in a half destroyed system. Everything seemed to work well during the installation, but after reboot I got the mess.

During boot it does not ask me which OS I would like to choose, as it was said in the installation routine. It always boots Windows, but the Windows partition on drive d: (30% of the disk) is gone and Win7(64) instead reports a RAW partition with the the entire capacity of around 500GB. My drive C: (SSD) and Drive E:(HD) seem to be ok though. But D: was my win program drive and so my win7 installation is nearly unusable.

Is there a way to revert the installation and get my partition on drive D. back ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do an "alongside Windows" install, the installer resizes the first partition and sticks a new one in after it for Ubuntu. That's what happened and that's why your "C" drive is smaller.

Furthermore, Windows uses a thoroughly broken logical approach to drive naming. So if you insert another partition into a system (as has happened here), Windows doesn't have a clue what to do. I'll stop raging on the inadequacies of Windows and let you read this:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Change-add-or-remove-a-drive-letter

You can manually change the letter assigned to a partition. Do that and fix your "programs drive" back to D. That should fix Windows for you.

After that,

- If you still want to use Ubuntu you can try fixing the Grub bootloader which doesn't appear to have detected the right disk to install its bootloader onto. You have a non-standard setup so you might find that just changing the boot priority of the system in your BIOS will fix that.
- If you don't, nuke that partition (you can do that from Windows or the LiveCD) and resize your C drive back up. This will probably play havoc with your D drive again, but you can fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Ubuntu has NOT changed the size of my boot  disk (The ssd). It either was not able to see the SSD or was not able to use the remaining 60GB as a boot partition for Ubuntu. Instead it obviously tried to install on my 1. HD, which had around 350 GB of free space. But instead of using this free space, it must have killed my win partition and was not able to install itself properly on it.

Comment: To make it clear: Drice C: , my SSD is also my BOOT disk for win7-64. The win programs are (were) on drive D: ...

Answer (score -1):

after installing this on my pc as a longside windows 8 i think we need to re thik the grub boot manger so it shows up windows installations as well as linux Ubuntu as ive noticed it delets the windows boot mgr and this causes windows to start as the windows os looks for its own boot mgr to work

but to the question above there isent at the moment which makes Ubuntu rubbish you will have to reinstall windows all over again but with out wiping the hard drive so you have all your files from windows

1. put your dvd/cd in to the drive press del f8 f10 f12 which ever it is to get in to bios
2. select the dvd drive to boot first and press any key when its prompts you
3. on windows 7 select your language  then click next it will give you 3 options i would select option 3 as this might fix windows with out reinstalling it click on repair windows click on advance and click on automatic repair windows it should work if it dont then that will tell you will deffently need to reinstall so back to square 1 click on install windows click on advance it will come in a white windows with a load of hard drives depending on how many you have in your system, select the hard drive you want dont click on anything else it will install windows with all the files intact once windows is installed you can delete Ubuntu from the hard in the system registry  i know its long winded but its what i have to do but i am going for my new hard drive in put Ubunty on and install windows on my ssd