# Permissions Issues after co-installing 21.04 along side 20.4.02

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, permissions, 21.04

I decided to install 21.04 using default Ubuntu-guided install along side 20.4.02. During the install I resized the original partitions to afford equal space to the two systems, and then ran the install. When booting back into 20.4.02 and attempting to move files around (on to an external drive) permissions seem to be lost.

Is my data on 20.4.02 now confined to this partition?

Similar questions such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110659/roll-back-of-ubuntu-installation-possible-to-get-a-win7-partition-back) seem to cover Windows/Ubuntu installs, so wanted to clarify likely outcomes from dual-booting Ubuntu only.

Comment: Did you use a VFAT or NTFS USB stick or disk for temporary storage of those files? If yes, that's why those permissions got lost: Both have no concept of Linux permissions or file ownership.

Comment: dev/sda1 EFI System Partition lives on fat32. I think I see the problem now! I assume that would this have been formatted ext4, there would also be preserved permissions. Thanks for taking the time to reply.